# Query with Join of tables is taking long time to execute

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle 11g. I have a query which is taking long time to execute for 150,000 records.

And the query is:

```
 insert /*+ APPEND NOLOGGING */ into CONCEPT_COUNTS_DIMENSION
 (select fa.c_fullname AS CONCEPT_PATH ,ltrim(SUBSTR(fa.c_fullname, 1,instr(fa.c_fullname, '\',-1,2))) AS PARENT_CONCEPT_PATH,count(distinct tpm.encounter_num) AS value,'Document_Count' as type
 from "I2B2METADATA"."I2B2_toinsert" fa ,"I2B2METADATA"."I2B2_toinsert" la ,I2B2DEMODATA.OBSERVATION_FACT_to_insert tpm ,i2b2demodata.PATIENT_DIMENSION p where 
 fa.c_fullname like '\a\b\c\%' and
 la.c_fullname like fa.c_fullname || '%' escape '`'
/*  and la.c_visualattributes like 'L%' */
 and tpm.patient_num = p.patient_num
 and la.c_basecode = tpm.concept_cd
 group by fa.c_fullname ,ltrim(SUBSTR(fa.c_fullname, 1,instr(fa.c_fullname, '\',-1,2))));
```

This query joins a table with it self and 2 other tables and selects distinct count of patients for the paths beneath it.

Can any one suggest how to tune this query to make it faster. I validated the indexes for these tables and generated statistics for 1% of data. Any other way I can proceed to make it faster?

Comment: Please look at "explain plan", then you can get hints on where to improve your query http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience, I have found letting the SQL engine try to figure out the joins to be time consuming.  I always specify the type of joins (INNER, LEFT, RIGHT etc...) and the fields the join is on.

I see that you do check index which is good.  I assume they are on the fields you use as your join keys.

The other thing I would look at is the GROUP BY clause.  If you are reading these into a table as it looks like you are trying to do, this puts some overhead on the query as it has to perform the calculations on the fields, then puts them in the desired organization.  I would try to remove it from the insert and then when you read from the table you put the data into, then perform the Group By.

Comment: There is no performance difference between old style and new style (SQL-92) joins. Query plans are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query written with proper full join syntax:

```
insert /*+ APPEND NOLOGGING */ into CONCEPT_COUNTS_DIMENSION
    select fa.c_fullname AS CONCEPT_PATH ,
           ltrim(SUBSTR(fa.c_fullname, 1,instr(fa.c_fullname, '\',-1,2))) AS PARENT_CONCEPT_PATH,
           count(distinct tpm.encounter_num) AS value,
           'Document_Count' as type
    from "I2B2METADATA"."I2B2_toinsert" fa join
         "I2B2METADATA"."I2B2_toinsert" la
         on la.c_fullname like fa.c_fullname || '%' escape '`' join
         I2B2DEMODATA.OBSERVATION_FACT_to_insert tpm 
         on la.c_basecode = tpm.concept_cd join
         i2b2demodata.PATIENT_DIMENSION p 
         on tpm.patient_num = p.patient_num 
    where fa.c_fullname like '\a\b\c\%' and
          /*  and la.c_visualattributes like 'L%' */
     group by fa.c_fullname, ltrim(SUBSTR(fa.c_fullname, 1,instr(fa.c_fullname, '\',-1,2))));
```

Likely the join between `fa` and `la` is taking a long time.  I assume the other dimensions are properly indexed.  An index on `c_fullname` might help.  However, I suspect that the root nodes of the tree are really expanding the amount of data being processed.